# Must NM cable from floor to wall go through sill plate?

Tags: electrical, wiring

In New or remodel with floors and walls open, When routing NM from a joist bay into a wall is it required or preferred to drill through the sill plate or is it ok/normal to route over the plate and make use of space available where the subfloor and wall board meet?

Comment: Think you would need a steel protective plate if the cable is not ~1 1/2 inch from the wall surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without putting a notch in the sill plate and then running the cable flat inside the notch and then protecting the cable with a nail plate.

NM cable has to be laid in such a way as to avoid physical damage. What you’re suggesting is just begging for a baseboard finish nail right through the cable. It’s not allowed by code for a good reason.